# StreetViewPanoramaCamera roll android

Tags: android, camera, google-street-view

I'm developing an Android app using Google StreetView.

I want to rotate the view using the rotation vector values from the accelerometer and gyroscope. For now, its working fine for bearing and tilt, but StreetViewPanoramaCamera doesn't have any method to rotate over z-axis (roll).

Here it is an example of my rotation code:

```
@Override
public void onOrientationChanged(float[] orientation) {
    if (mStreetViewPanorama != null) {
        StreetViewPanoramaCamera camera = new StreetViewPanoramaCamera.Builder()
                .bearing(orientation[0] * (180 / (float) Math.PI))
                .tilt(-orientation[1] * (180 / (float) Math.PI))
                // .roll is missing!!!!
                .zoom(1f)
                .build();
        mStreetViewPanorama.animateTo(camera, 0);
    }
}
```

[StreetView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.street&hl=es) android native app includes this functionality so I guess this can be done in one or another way.

I've tried to rotate the fragment without using the camera, but it's not working as expected. See images below:

[image]
[image]

It's like it rotates an invisible layer with Google Copyright but not the streetview images.

Hope anyone can help.